# how can I set a height and width for this map in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new and I am working using this map. I have a div container called: `#statesvg` where I want the map to adapt to its size. but this one is cut.

[image]

in which part of the code can I modify the height and width of the map?

Thank you very much

http://bl.ocks.org/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922

```
//I get the actual size of the div
var width = document.getElementById('statesvg').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('statesvg').offsetWidth;
.
.
.
Same code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than scaling the entire svg (or portions of it), you can change the projection. The projection determines how much space your features occupy, no matter what the svg size. The easiest method would be to use `projection.fitSize()` in d3v4+:

`projection.fitSize([width,height],feature);`

Where `width` and `height` are your svg dimensions, and `feature` is your geojson feature collection (`json` in your example, not `json.features`, it takes an object, not an array). This method sets the scale and translate of the projection so that your features are centered and scaled appropriately for your svg/canvas.

Alternatively, given that all `fitSize` does is set the translate and scale of a projection, you could modify these attributes directly to set the appropriate scale and translate. Since your example centers the projection with `[width/2,height/2]` this is will already adapt to provided dimensions. Consequently, all you need to do is set the scale. If the scale value of 1000 is appropriate for a width of 960 and height of 500, then a scale of 2000 will be appropriate for a width of 480 and a height of 250. With this we can just use some simple math:

`var scale = 960/width*1000; // assuming that width is always limiting`

If width or height could be limiting, find the scale value for both using the above logic and take the higher scale value. Then apply the scale to the map the same as your example does now: `projection.scale(scale);`. This lets you scale the map easily, and in d3v3 as well (like your example block).

Comment: thank you very much! is a complete answer, but if for example the height is 960 and the width is 400. How can I make it fit perfectly to the container? var scale = 960 /400*1000; ?

Comment: can you help me with this modification please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956488/how-can-i-exactly-fit-the-size-of-a-map-to-the-container

Comment: If you have excess width or height you might have empty space - the aspect ratio of the map doesn't change with scale. So, if your map initially fills an area of 960x500 fairly well, it won't fit an area of 400x960 unless you stretch it - which usually isn't what you want in a map projection. Empty space aside, to fit the entire map in the view, take the higher of: 960/width*1000 or 500/height*1000 and use it as your scale.

Comment: Also, updated the answer, I reversed my fractions for some reason.

Comment: what do you mean about that?

Comment: About which part? If the aspect ratio part - you'll need to stretch each axis of the map to get a perfect fill (a rectangular bounding box with the same dimensions as the svg container): a square feature won't fill a rectangular container. If about the changes to the answer, I had just messed up my fractions, you have it right in your comment.