# How can I exactly fit the size of a map to the container?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing a map of the United States, and I would like the map to adapt to the size of the `div#statesvg`

```
<div id="statesvg" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

the size of `div#statesvg` is dynamic.

I only want by default that the map fits exactly to the div that contains it. When I load the page I want the map to adjust to the size of the div.

[image]

My problem:

[image]

I need something like this:
[image]

```
var width = document.getElementById('statesvg').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('statesvg').offsetWidth;       

// D3 Projection
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])    // translate to center of screen
                   .scale([1000]);          // scale things down so see entire US

// Define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()               // path generator that will convert GeoJSON to SVG paths
             .projection(projection);  // tell path generator to use albersUsa projection


svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
    // Get data value
    var value = d.properties.visited;
    if (value) {
    //If value exists…
    return color(value);
    } else {
    //If value is undefined…
    return "rgb(213,222,217)";
    }
});
```

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pm1qYdKCYDPJNm2lsZZV?p=preview

Comment: @pmkroeker not friend, it is not the same, the previous question asked how to do so that it would not be cut. This time it is to adjust all the contents of the map precisely in the container.

Comment: @pmkroeker I also added code based on the previous feedback.

Comment: You are adding your whole map into the body. Do you want it in the div? Updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sGjumBTG9ObvLj4S2D4Z?p=preview)

Comment: @pmkroeker Your plunker does not solve my problem. I just want the map to adapt exactly to the size of my div

Comment: @pmkroeker look this picture please: https://i.imgur.com/6BrAcW0.jpg

Comment: I asked for clarification earlier but you want it to change size as the window does?

Comment: @pmkroeker I have updated the image. I only want by default that the map fits exactly to the div that contains it. When I load the page I want the map to adjust to the size of the div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165739/discussion-between-pmkroeker-and-yavg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V56bNcsONOpz6SZpwTHo?p=preview). The projection scale was modified to `.scale((height * 1.25))` and the svg is now being appended in to the `statesvg` div and not the body.